# Fedora 12 No wireless networks detected

Tags: fedora, wifi, rpm, broadcom

I have just bought a Dell Inspiron 1510 and loaded Fedora 12 along with Windows. I cannot detect any wireless networks through my network applet on the tool bar.

```
$:lscpi
12:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4727 (rev 01)
13:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
```

I installed the following rpms:

```
kmod-wl-2.6.31.5-127.fc12.i686.PAE-5.10.91.9.3-3.fc12.6.i686
kmod-wl-PAE-5.10.91.9.3-3.fc12.6.i686
broadcom-wl-5.10.91.9.3-1.fc12.noarch
```

and restarted the system but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Check the output of `lsmod` to see if they are being loaded; if not, try to `modprobe $module` to load it manually.
If this does not help you are probably using the wrong driver for that particular card.
If it works, run `depmod -a` to regenerate module dependencies. It should load it automatically afterwards.